# How to receive Broadcast messages from local broadcast manager?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working in Android with Xamarin.
I have a broadcast receiver that catches the button on a headset like so:

```
 public class MyMediaButtonBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public string ComponentName { get { return Class.Name; } }

        private MediaMetadataRetriever reader = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action != Intent.ActionMediaButton)
                return;

            var keyEvent = (KeyEvent)intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraKeyEvent);

            switch (keyEvent.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keycode.Headsethook:
                    break;
                case Keycode.MediaPlay:
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity_Player.ctx, "PLAY", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
                case Keycode.MediaPlayPause:

                    break;
                case Keycode.MediaNext:
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity_Player.ctx, "NEXT", ToastLength.Short).Show();

                    break;
                case Keycode.MediaPrevious:
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity_Player.ctx, "Prev", ToastLength.Short).Show();

                    break;
            }
        }
```

Now, what has to happen once the headsethook is being fired is I need to send another, local broadcast to my mainactivity.

This means, I need in my main activity A listener function that can now fire functions in within the main activity. But I havent found anything on how to receive a local broadcast only on how to send it. What can I try next?

### Edit

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionMediaButton })]
public class MyMediaButtonBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public string ComponentName { get { return Class.Name; } }

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Action != Intent.ActionMediaButton)
            return;

        var keyEvent = (KeyEvent)intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraKeyEvent);

        switch (keyEvent.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keycode.Headsethook:
                Activity_Player.Instance.PlayOrPauseLogic();
                break;
            case Keycode.MediaPlay:
                Toast.MakeText(Activity_Player.ctx, "PLAY", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                Activity_Player.Instance.PlayOrPauseLogic();
                break;
            case Keycode.MediaPlayPause:
                Activity_Player.Instance.PlayOrPauseLogic();
                break;
            case Keycode.MediaNext:
                Toast.MakeText(Activity_Player.ctx, "NEXT", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                if(Activity_Player.CurrentSongObject != null)
                    Activity_Player.Instance.ChooseRandomNewSongAndPlay(false);
                break;
            case Keycode.MediaPrevious:
                Toast.MakeText(Activity_Player.ctx, "Prev", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                if (Activity_Player.CurrentSongObject != null)
                    Activity_Player.mediaPlayer.SeekTo(0);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I read your question again and again, but can't comprehend what you want to achieve. Could you please elaborate? AFA I understand, you've got the action from headset, now you wanna hook this action to MainActivity, is this correct?

Comment: Right, so most of my app logic is within my main activity. But the receiver is another class. I read, that if I want to fire logic from my main acitivty after having received something from my broadcast receiver class I need to fire another broadcast to my main activity called a "local broadcast". This would fire a function in within my main activity from where I can fire the logic there. But I cannot get from my broadcast receiver to my main activity. So you are correct sir!

Comment: Kind sir, please make this receiver an inner class inside main activity, if it's used only for this purpose, which I suppose to be true.

Comment: Well, I can do that ofc but even then I cannot just call a function from the main activity since it is still another class...?

Comment: I think we can register a broadcast receiver for `MainActivity`. So, once we get the action from first receiver, that is `MyMediaButtonBroadcastReceiver`, we should fire an action, via an intent ofc, containing play,pause or stop info. This info will be caught inside the receiver of `MainActivity`. What you've read about using a `LocalBroadcastManager` is true, you can use it to fire the action for the main activity to catch.

Comment: Great, I have not been able to find any example here. would you mind giving my very rudimentary code? please?

Comment: What does BroadcastReciever look like? Does it fire events that you can listen to?

Comment: Actually I found a simple way: I am creating a public static instance of my activity. Now I can freely pick a function from my main acticity in my broadcast recevier. I will post the receiver now:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to receive Broadcast messages from local broadcast manager?

Lets assume you have a `BroadcastReceiver` called ServiceBroadcastReceiver that acts upon Intent extras. In this example, if I receive an "play" intent extra, I will do something with that information.

Make this an inner-class of your Activity:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class ServiceBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    Context context;

    public ServiceBroadcastReceiver(Context context)
    {
       this.context = context;
    }
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.HasExtra("play"))
        {
           // sent a "play" cmd, do something.
           // context is your activity, you can call methods on it
           (context as SomeActivity)?.PlayReceived();
        }
    }
}
```

Now to send a broadcast to that receiver:

```
var intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(ServiceBroadcastReceiver));
intent.PutExtra("play", true);
SendBroadcast(intent);
```

When your Activity is running, you can register to receive these broadcasts:

In your OnResume override, you can create/register it:

```
 // serviceBroadcastReceiver is a class level variable 
 serviceBroadcastReceiver = new ServiceBroadcastReceiver(this);
 RegisterReceiver(packageBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

In your `OnPause` override, unregister it and clean up:

```
UnregisterReceiver(serviceBroadcastReceiver);
serviceBroadcastReceiver.Dispose();
serviceBroadcastReceiver = null;
```

Comment: Okay great, this works fine, sure. But now I have my main activity class in which there are function i need to fire now. How do i get from the OnReceive from the broadcast receiver to the an OnReceive function in within my main activity?

Comment: Thank you, but I still do not understand where exactly it receives anything. I would need a function in my main activity that overrides something like "OnReceive" and when I send something out, I would need to trigger this function. I dont understand how to respond to the received signal...

Comment: @innomotionmedia I updated my answer, use an inner-class, see the changes to ServiceBroadcastReceiver

Comment: fantastic! however i handled it with making a single instance of my activity which is quicker but dirtier. thanks a lot!